# "; missing before instruction"

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

While using this code I get "; missing before instruction" error.
I believe this could have a simple explanation, but actually I can't understand what's wrong.

Also tried with switch/case statements but get same error... there could be something wrong with array...

```
function motori(){

  var esito = [];

  for (var j = 6; j < 16; j++) {
    var rngRiga= foglio.getRange("AJ"+j+":BT"+j).getValues(); //store in array
    var riga = rngRiga[0].join('-'); // build a string with array
    Logger.log("riga = " + riga);    // all right till now

    if (riga.search("KOS") > -1){
      var esito[j] = "KOS";}     //<---- here highlights the error
    else if (riga.search("OKS") > -1){
      var esito[j] = "OKS";}
    else if (riga.search("AN") > -1){
      var esito[j] = "AN";}  
    else if (riga.search("OK") > -1){
      var esito[j] = "OK";}
    else if (riga.search("KO") > -1){
      var esito[j] = "KO";}


    Logger.log("result = " + esito);
    Logger.log("j = " + j);
  }
}
```

What I need is a new array with the result of the if statements.

Comment: Note that since j is not starting from 0, your result array is going to have very unintuitive behavior and won't contain as many defined values as its `length` property will suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to you already declared the variable ***esito*** and then inside the if you try to declare it again, so that will cause a problem because you're trying to create the same variable again. change Your code as follow:

```
function motori(){

  var esito = [];

  for (var j = 6; j < 16; j++) {
    var rngRiga= foglio.getRange("AJ"+j+":BT"+j).getValues(); //store in array
    var riga = rngRiga[0].join('-'); // build a string with array
    Logger.log("riga = " + riga);    // all right till now

    if(riga.search("KOS") > -1){
     esito[j] = "KOS";}     //<---- here highlights the error
    else if (riga.search("OKS") > -1){
       esito[j] = "OKS";}
    else if (riga.search("AN") > -1){
       esito[j] = "AN";}  
    else if (riga.search("OK") > -1){
       esito[j] = "OK";}
    else if (riga.search("KO") > -1){
       esito[j] = "KO";}


    Logger.log("result = " + esito);
    Logger.log("j = " + j);
  }
}
```